TLS Connection successful with mismatched CA
Requirement:
I'm working on the following requirement. I have two devices that act like server and a client communicating over a LAN cable. They exchange some data and I'm trying to secure the data using TLS.
What I've done and the Issue I'm facing:

Got a CA private key and CA cert from a colleague of mine who worked on a similar requirement few years back

Using the CA key and cert, I created certs and keys for my server and client using OpenSSL in the following way


Private Keys:
openssl genrsa -out private\server.key.pem 2048
openssl genrsa -out private\client.key.pem 2048

Server CSR and Cert:
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -key private\server.key.pem -new -sha256 -subj "/CN=Server" -out csr\server.csr.pem
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -batch -extensions server_cert -days 730 -notext -md sha256 -in csr\server.csr.pem -out certs\server.cert.pem -passin pass:myPassword

Client CSR and Cert:
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -key private\client.key.pem -new -sha256 -subj "/CN=Client" -out csr\client.csr.pem
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -batch -extensions iot_cert -days 730 -notext -md sha256 -in csr\client.csr.pem -out certs\client.cert.pem -passin pass:myPassword


Once the certs and keys are generated, I append the CA cert to the server and client certs. These will be the certificates of my server and client. I have a Root CA certificate as well. Then I loaded the server cert, server private key, root CA cert on to the Server and Client cert, Client Private key, root CA cert on to the Client

I use wolfSSL in my application to do the handshake and connection. I had written code for that already and when I loaded the certs and rebooted my devices, the connection was successful and they exchanged the data

I noticed the issue when I tested the following negative scenario: I removed the certs and keys from Client. I created a new batch of them using the following commands,


openssl -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout caKey.pem -out caCert.pem
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout clientKey.pem -out clientCsr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in clientCsr.pem -days 365 -CA caCert.pem -CAkey caKey.pem -CAcreateserial -out clientCert.pem

I loaded these on to the client and tried initiating connection. I was expecting them to not connect since they are signed by different CA. But, they ended up connecting. This is the issue that I'm facing
Debugging:
To test whether the problem is my application or the certificates, I used OpenSSL to run a server and client using the following commands
openssl s_server -cert serverCert.pem -key serverKey.pem -CAfile rootCA.pem -accept 4433
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cert WrongClientCert.pem -key WrongClientKey.pem -CAfile caCert.pem

It connected here as well. This confirmed to me that the problem might not be with my application and maybe with the certs and/ or the way OpenSSL and WolfSSL is configured. I checked online and it looks like the commands I used to generate the files seem to be correct. I'm stuck here as I'm not very familiar with the configuration settings of OpenSSL/ WolfSSL.
To help anyone answering this further, here are some information:
Extensions definition in my openssl.cnf:
[ iot_cert ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE,pathlen:0
nsCertType = client 
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, emailProtection
 
[ server_cert ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

My application code server side:
//I'm doing proper error checking, not shown here in this snippet
wolfSSL_Init();
WOLFSSL_CTX* pTmpsslCtx = wolfSSL_CTX_new(wolfTLS_server_method());
wolfSSL_CTX_set_verify(pTmpWolfsslCtx, WOLFSSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
wolfSSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(pTmpWolfsslCtx, 9);
wolfSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(pTmpWolfsslCtx, "pathToRootCA", NULL);
wolfSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(pTmpWolfsslCtx, "pathToPrivateKeyServer", WOLFSSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
wolfSSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(pTmpWolfsslCtx, "pathToServerCert");
WOLFSSL* pTmpWolfssl = wolfSSL_new(pTmpWolfsslCtx);

My application code client side:
//I'm doing proper error checking, not shown here in this snippet
wolfSSL_Init();
WOLFSSL_CTX* pTmpsslCtx = wolfSSL_CTX_new(wolfTLS_client_method());
wolfSSL_CTX_set_verify(pTmpWolfsslCtx, WOLFSSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
wolfSSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(pTmpWolfsslCtx, 9);
wolfSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(pTmpWolfsslCtx, "pathToRootCA", NULL);
wolfSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(pTmpWolfsslCtx, "pathToPrivateKeyClient", WOLFSSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
wolfSSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(pTmpWolfsslCtx, "pathToClientCert");
WOLFSSL* pTmpWolfssl = wolfSSL_new(pTmpWolfsslCtx);
wolfSSL_connect(pTmpWolfssl);

I'm stuck here and any inputs on why this connection is successful despite CA not matching would be helpful. Let me know if any of what I've done is incorrect. Thank You for your time!

I'm not familiar with WolfSSL, but I'm guessing that setting verification to WOLFSSL_VERIFY_NONE on the client side simply disables all authentication and leaves you wide open to MiTM attacks. On the server side, it just means the client is never asked to authenticate so the client never uses its TLS credentials.

Thank you for the reply. I suspected that initially, but even when OpenSSL connected, I stopped doubting that line. Maybe OpenSSL has some configuration internally that is set to NO VERIFICATION? But it wouldn't make sense as it would break the concept of security. One might expect the default setting to be VERIFY_PEER since security is of more concern here

In the TLS protocol, client authentication is optional but server authentication is mandatory. In your openssl example, your server is serving a correctly constructed server cert and your client trusts caCert.pem which (presumably) signed serverCert.pem. So client is able to authenticate the server. The client has been given invalid credentials, but you haven't told the server to request that the client must authenticate. If you want the server to require client authentication you must supply the -Verify <integer> option to openssl s_server.

My name is Anthony and I am a member of the wolfSSL team.
a few suggestions and pointers:

Note that openSSL by default does not actually verify certificates during a TLS connection; so your debugging step with s_server and s_client didn't really tell you anything.
Typically the side being verified does not send over the Root CA.  For example, if the client is verifying the server, the server does not send over the Root CA; they assume the client already possesses the Root CA cert. So, no need to append the Root CA.
You might want to use the example server/client that comes with wolfSSL first.  You should use the -A, -c and -k options to specify the certs and keys. This might be a good sanity check.
https://www.wolfssl.com/certificate-chain-chain-trust/ gives some guidance on certificate chains.  Please do have a read.
To get a better idea of what is going on turn on debug logging. --enable-debug at configuration time and call wolfSSL_Debugging_ON()
wolfSSL provides pre-sales support. For better quality of service, you can contact us at support@wolfssl.com. This will also allow you to share details about your setup in a confidential manner.

I hope these suggestions and pointers are helpful.
Warm regards, Anthony

Hello Anthony! Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your inputs. I have mailed wolfSSL support for further help as you suggested.
